# primary expression expected before token

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error "expected primary-expression before ‘;’ token" for line 26. The line that gives the error is

```
cout << "Enter a number: "<<;
```

And I haven't been able to figure out what this even means from seeing other peoples results. Here's the rest of my code.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int guess = 2;
    int countinue = 1;
    int num = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int x = 0;

    while(countinue==1) 
    {
        cout << "Enter a number: "<<;
        cin >> num;

        for(x=0;x==0;cin>>x) 
        {
            result = num / guess;
            guess = (guess + result) / 2;
            result = num / guess;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<<;` because you can't insert *nothing* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `<<;` supposed to do? You only need to use `<<`, the stream insertion operator, to add new pieces of output to your stream. You don't need to use it to add the `;` to the statement...

Try `cout << "Enter a number:";`.

Comment: Oh thank you. I only just started so I wasn't sure what << did.